# How to customize two way databinding in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

HTML:

`<select data-ng-options="o.id as o.device for o in deviceList" data-ng-model="selectedDeviceID"></select>
    <input type="text" id="deviceWidth" ng-model="deviceList[selectedDeviceID].width" placeholder="width"/>`

Data:

```
$scope.deviceList = [{id: 0, device: 'Apple iPhone 5', width:320,height:568},
              {id: 1, device: 'Nokia Lumia 920', width:320,height:533},
              {id: 2, device: 'Samsung Galaxy S III', width:360,height:640}]
```

When I select devicename in dropdown, respective width will be displayed in textbox. It is working fine. But I dont want change the original values, when I change value in textbox.

Simply, I want to show the value in textbox and editable. But I dont want this value to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You add `ng-change="updateDeviceWidthTextbox()"` to the select, change the model of the input-field to something like `ng-model="deviceWidthTextbox"` and in the controller you implement the function:

```
$scope.updateDeviceWidthTextbox = function() {
     $scope.deviceWidthTextbox = deviceList[selectedDeviceID].width;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i didn't understand you correctly. Hope I could help you.

```
<select ng-change="changed(selectedDeviceID)" data-ng-options="o.id as o.device for o in deviceList" data-ng-model="selectedDeviceID"></select>
<input type="text" id="deviceWidth" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="width"/>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.changed = function (selectedDeviceID) {
    $scope.inputText = $scope.deviceList[selectedDeviceID].width
});
```